# How to disable next Stage on Form field validation in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: javascript, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way to disable the next stage "event" when a requiered field in the current form entity is empty.

The field is not present in the process flow.

With the addOnStageChange event we are not able to "cancel" the change.

```
Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange(handler);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817878.aspx#BKMK_addOnStageSelected

Comment: can't you can check the value of the required field in the function and then run your code?

Comment: Do you have some additional requirements apart from checking if the field is empty? If not, would it be sufficient to set the field as required in the BPF (such that you get a warning when trying to move to the next stage: "You have to complete the required steps before you can advance.")?

Comment: Instead of preventing the stage change, how about using the [movePrevious](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817878.aspx#BKMK_movePrevious) method to force them to go back if the field is empty?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can't add the field in question to the process flow, and you run out of options, you could take the brutish approach of hiding the process flow control altogether until the field is populated. Definitely not ideal, but an option.